# slideshow click to change image

Tags: jquery, plugins, slideshow

I'm using this [plugin](http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel) and I would like like to know if I'm missing something in the options.

Is it possible to click the image to go to change to the next image?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. The plugin looks for the buttons and that's about it.**

Fortunately for you they give the source-code back so it will be easy to adapt it in order to work the way you want.